# How can I associate an smart outlet with "lights"?

Tags: google-home, smart-plugs

I recently added a Eufy Smart Plug to my setup. It's currently controlling a floor light. However, Google Home doesn't recognize it as a lamp, so when I say "turn on the lights" or "turn off the lights", it isn't included.

How can I tell Google Home that this plug is controlling a light?

Answer (score 10):

Google Home seems to figure out the "type" of an outlet via the *name*. If the *name* includes the word "lamp" or "light", then it's considered a light and will become part of the light set, and participate in the "turn on/off the lights" commands.

So, change the name of the device to something that includes "lamp", wait a while, and eventually it will be grouped in the "lights" category.

[image: Living room lights screenshot show "lamp" in the outlet names]

Comment: How long is "a while"? I'm trying to change a device from a lamp to not a lamp, so I renamed it to "Water Pump" and now I'm waiting.

Comment: You can say "Sync devices" to Google Assistant to force a sync. I had to rename the device in the manufacturer's app, not in Google Home, and then the device type changed OK.

Comment: That was too simple! It's not the first time I've been shown that Google is brighter than me... FYI, if you'd prefer, you can use "light" instead of "lamp". It is, of course, that smart.